# make: c: command not found

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, cygwin

I am attempting to run my make file however i am getting the following two errors:

make: c: command not found

and

make: o: command not found

I am attempting to do this inside of cygwin. I have g++ and make installed on it, however when I run the make file I receive these errors.

Any ideas?

The makefile:

```
all: MergeSort clean

MergeSort: main.o MergeSort.o
    $g++ -o MergeSort main.o MergeSort.o

main.o: main.cpp MergeSort.h
    $g++ -c main.cpp

MergeSort.o: MergeSort.cpp MergeSort.h
    $g++ -c MergeSort.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *o

cleanall:
    rm -rf *o *exe
```

Comment: Post your makefile, and how you are running it.

Comment: http://codepad.org/UPInzxwg this is the make file and I am running it by typing "make" while in the directory that it is in (there are only my files and the makefile there.)

Comment: I added the Makefile in the body of the question. Don't use sites likes codepad or pastebin when posting code to SO: if your code sample ever disappear, the question would become meaningless. Moreover it's really annoying to have to open another web page to see a source code, especially when it is that small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the `$` from the `$g++` lines.  It's trying to expand some variable that doesn't exist, and is swallowing up the "`$g++ -`" from your commands.

The syntax for using a variable is:

```
$(CXX) -c main.cpp
```

In this case, `CXX` is the path to the C++ compiler, which is defined for you.  You can change it by adding the following line to your makefile:

```
CXX = g++
```

If you are trying to avoid echoing back the command make is running, use `@` instead of `$`.

Answer (score 1):

$g++ is not defined in that makefile, so the command becomes

```
-o MergeSort main.o MergeSort.o
```

and

```
-c main.cpp
```

Either drop the $ from $g++ and use g++, or define the variable in your makefile.

```
CXX = g++
all: MergeSort clean

MergeSort: main.o MergeSort.o
    $CXX -o MergeSort main.o MergeSort.o

main.o: main.cpp MergeSort.h
    $CXX -c main.cpp

MergeSort.o: MergeSort.cpp MergeSort.h
    $CXX -c MergeSort.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *o

cleanall:
    rm -rf *o *exe
```

Comment: I think you should exchange `$CXX` by `$(CXX)` for GNU Make (the OP seems to ask about).